# Repeat rows at top of printed page

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, openoffice-calc

In Excel, under Page Setup, there is an option for "Print Titles", where you can specify a number of rows to repeat at the top of the printed page, as well as a number of columns to repeat at the left of a printed page.

Is there a similar setting in OpenOffice?  If so, under what menu item would it be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link that should be able to help you out: 
http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Printing_rows_or_columns_on_every_page